# Numpy: reshaping multiple times makes objects unequal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to run some reshape operations in numpy but seem to be unable to accomplish something that seems quite straightforward.

The following works just fine:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(55, 100, 3)

b = None
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    r = X[:, i:i+1, :]
    b = r if not np.any(b) else np.concatenate((b, r), axis=1)

assert np.all(X == b.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2])) # succeeds
```

However, when I attempt to reshape `r` before adding it to the rows in `b`, I seem to be unable to reshape the final `b` into the shape of `X`:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(55, 100, 3)

b = None
for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    r = X[:, i:i+1, :].reshape(1, X.shape[0] * X.shape[2])
    b = r if not np.any(b) else np.concatenate((b, r), axis=1)

assert np.all(X == b.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2])) # fails
```

I know there are better ways to accomplish this kind of operation. I'm simplifying a more complex situation.

Does anyone know how I can make the second assertion succeed while maintaining the general structure of the second snippet? Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, there are probably ways to do this better, but if you absolutely want to stick to your structure, you just need to re-shuffle your indices:

```
assert np.all(X == np.transpose(b.reshape(X.shape[1], X.shape[0], X.shape[2]), axes=(1,0,2)))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks very much @Julien! If you could provide a brief gloss on transposition here, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: not sure what you are asking for... you are essentially messing up the order of your elements, so you need to reorder them...

Comment: Ah no worries I'll check the documentation on transpose, thanks very much for this reference